# How to Make a Pop-Up Form's TextBox Required

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an MS Word 2010 document I did not create.

When you open the document you get a small 'Form' pop-up window with text-boxes to be filled. The form will populate the Word document when the user clicks an 'OK' button on the form. The 'Form' was created in Visual Basic. I have an image of the form but it looks like I don't have enough rep points yet to post it.

How can I make a TextBox in the form named 'txtcnsl' required when a user clicks the 'OK' button? And then throw an alert error or something similar saying something like "You are required to fill in text box with xyz info". The code for the form is below. It looks like the 'OK' button is named 'cmdOk_Click()'. Also where would I add the new code?

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
    ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("caseno").Range.Text = txtcaseno.Value
    .Bookmarks("resp").Range.Text = txtresp.Value
    .Bookmarks("resp2").Range.Text = txtresp.Value
    .Bookmarks("barno").Range.Text = txtmember.Value
    .Bookmarks("type").Range.Text = cbotype.Value
    .Bookmarks("sbexh").Range.Text = txtsbexh.Value
    .Bookmarks("rexh").Range.Text = txtrexh.Value
    .Bookmarks("transno").Range.Text = txttransno.Value
    .Bookmarks("respstreet").Range.Text = txtrespstreet.Value
    .Bookmarks("respcity").Range.Text = txtrespcity.Value
    .Bookmarks("cnsl").Range.Text = txtcnsl.Value
    .Bookmarks("cnslstreet").Range.Text = txtcnslstreet.Value
    .Bookmarks("cnslcity").Range.Text = txtcnslcity.Value
End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Unload Me
        ActiveWindow.View.ShowBookmarks = False
End Sub


Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Frame2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label4_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub txtcaseno_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub txtcnsl_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub txtcnslcity_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub txtcnslstreet_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub txtresp_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub txtrespcity_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub txtrespstreet_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    cbotype.AddItem "Rule 1-110 Violation Proceeding"
    cbotype.AddItem "Reinstatement Proceeding"
    cbotype.AddItem "Revocation of Probation Proceeding"
    cbotype.AddItem "Conviction Proceeding"
    cbotype.AddItem "Rule 9.20 Proceeding"
    cbotype.AddItem "Original Proceeding"
    cbotype.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()
    'exit if txtcnsl has no value
    If Len(txtcnsl.Value) = 0 Then
        Msgbox "Please fill in blah blah blah"
        Exit Sub  
    End If 

    '...
    'rest of your code
    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks great, very helpful. I was able to take this code and expand on it to get exactly what I needed, Thanks!